# Special character in text file when removing line

Tags: c

I am new to C and I am trying to remove a line from a text file, the code I have removes the specified line but leaves a special `�` characters at the end and I have no idea why or how to fix it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void removeBook(int line) {
    FILE *file = fopen("bookrecord.csv", "r");
    int currentline = 1;
    char character;

    FILE *tempfile = fopen("temp.csv", "w");

    while(character != EOF) {
        character = getc(file);
        printf("%c", character);
        if (character == '\n') {
            currentline++;
        }
        if (currentline != line) {
            putc(character, tempfile);
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    fclose(tempfile);
    remove("bookrecord.csv");
    rename("temp.csv", "bookrecord.csv");
}

void main() {
    removeBook(2);
}
```

In my text file, I have `Test1` and `Test2` on separate lines, `Test1` on line 1 and `Test2` on line 2. When the function is run it removes line 2 (`Test2`) but leaves the special `�` character in its place. Why?

Comment: `character = getc(file);` <<-- `getc()` returns an **int**. (and `character`is not initialized)  [Plus: you have  to swap the two `if(..)`  parts]

Comment: How would I change the character = getc(file); to get the return value I want? I had a little play around but still get the same special character. I also thought character is initialised at the top with char character;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems in the code:

- `character` must be defined as an `int` to handle all byte values and the special value `EOF` returned by `getc()`.
- you do not test if the files were successfully open.
- `character` is uninitialized in the first test, the behavior is undefined.
- You always output the `character` read, even at the end of file, so you store a `'\377'` byte value at the end of the output file, displayed as `�` on your system, and as `ÿ` on some other systems.
- you should increment the line number **after** you output the newline as it is part of the current line.
- the prototype for `main` is `int main()`, not `void main()`.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int removeBook(int line) {
    FILE *file, *tempfile;
    int c, currentline;

    file = fopen("bookrecord.csv", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf("cannot open input file bookrecord.csv: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    tempfile = fopen("temp.csv", "w");
    if (tempfile == NULL) {
        fprintf("cannot open temporary file temp.csv: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        fclose(tempfile);
        return 1;
    }

    currentline = 1;
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        if (currentline != line) {
            putc(c, tempfile);
        }
        if (c == '\n') {
            currentline++;
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    fclose(tempfile);

    if (remove("bookrecord.csv")) {
        fprintf("cannot remove input file bookrecord.csv: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    if (rename("temp.csv", "bookrecord.csv")) {
        fprintf("cannot rename temporary file temp.csv: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    return removeBook(2);
}
```